# How to configure the client certificate in Power BI desktop to authenticate with mutual TLS

Tags: connectivity, powerbi

I am trying to connect to a private data source from Power BI desktop. Data source has its own trusted root authority. I created my personal certificate and private key signed by this root CA. I configured the PFX file of my certificate in "personal" folder in windows' certificate management UI. I also added the root CA as trusted CA.

Power BI desktop does not seem to pick up this certificate and fails the mutual TLS authentication. I added my cert to firefox and opened the server url, it is able to authenticate me fine using mutual TLS there.

What am I doing missing?

FHIR data source connector. JPA over Postgres is the actual server connection.

Error message:

> the request was aborted: could not create ssl/TLS secure channel.

When I connect from firefox, it is using TLS 1.3 for mutual authentication. Does Power BI not support TLS 1.3? The server supports both TLS 1.2 and 1.3

Comment: Does your data source use/support Tls 1.2, or an earlier version? Is [your desktop configured](https://www.cloudfronts.com/power-bi-transport-layer-security-settings-tls/) to use Tls 1.2?

Comment: I just checked the server supports both TLS 1.2 and 1.3